# Symfony2 + Doctrine + FormType, relations and dynamic adding rows

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, doctrine-orm

first look: [image]

i have made this DB structure with entities than dumped and visualised.

Adding things to DB from phpMyAdmin or displaying data from code is no problem, but when i try to build form using formtype like:

1. main form is CV (curriculum vitae)
2. this contains one text field
3. relation to skills of user (skill, degree) (now i can only select existing skill of the user, added through phpmyadmin)
4. same as skills for employments, schools,..

my mind want to blow from weirdness. Can someone help me?

I want to build form where i can fill anything on one page. Eg.:

1. user writes something about himself
2. for example he clicks on add new school, and form for schools will appear, if he have more schools, he can add another (without reloading page and saving actual form)
3. same with employments, click add new,...
4. at skills he can select the skill he knows (for example C++ Programing), click add and than can select or enter the degree (0 Begginer, 1...3 Expert). Adding more needs to be possible as with 3. and 2.
5. as final step he clicks on the "Save CV"

And anything done.

I have tried:

```
         ->add('skills', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new SkillsType(),
                'label' => 'Skills',
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                    ))
```

With Template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% for skill in form.skills %}
    <li>
        {{ form_widget(skill) }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

to add skills then i wanted to use the same for adding employments.

At wort i will make manual form with couple of javascript.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Collection field type is what your using. If you havent already its work looking at the Documentation for it.

You can do what you want by using the prototype property which Symfony will add to your form if you add the `allow_add` option in your form builder.

[Collection Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

Comment: thankyou i wil lcheck it tommorow, you answer seems to work in theory

Comment: Oh its fantastic, works like charm with custom prototype data template. Thank you once more

Comment: Your welcome, I have used it before and yeah it seems to work. If I have to do it again I would improve the JS they recommend but thats just me :)